# Amplitude associated with a range of frequencies in FFT

Tags: audio, fft, html5-audio, web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

The [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API) function `getByteFrequencyData` returns an unsigned byte array containing the frequency data for an audio sample. How can I extract the mean value associated with a range of frequencies? I'm looking for a function of the form

```
    function getMeanValue(minimumFrequency, maximumFrequency)
```

The purpose of this function I'm looking for is to split the audio sample into various frequency bands (since pitch is perceived logarithmically) from, for example, 0-200 Hz, 200-400 Hz, 400-800 Hz, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just average the values that fall in that range.  Depending on your flexibility of bands, that may be more or less easy - if you want the mean value from 200-400Hz, for example, in a 44.1kHz audioContext, you'll have to do some more complex interpolation math, but it's not super-hard.  If you just want some estimation, it's easier, since the buckets are more already arranged linearly across [0,Nyquist frequency].